# Remove proxy temporarily

Tags: apt, proxy

I am using a proxy for my college wifi and I set it in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.`
While using my home wifi I was unable to download from `bash`. So I unset `http_proxy` (`http_proxy=""`). Still it didn't work. It is trying to connect to same proxy of my college. Also I commented whatever I wrote in `/etc/apt/apt.conf`.  It was not working so I deleted it from the file.
Still I am failing to do it.

Comment: Keep in mind that environment variables are loaded at login of your terminal.  So, you need to exit and reload your terminal.  Also, firefox has its own Proxy configuration, so you might need to look into that (Well, obviously you mention apt, so that's not firefox.  Still needed to mention it)

Comment: Sorry but I am a new user ... Can you help me with it?

Comment: In your terminal type `env | grep -i proxy` and give me the output

Comment: http_proxy=http://10.1.101.150:3128/

Comment: It is the proxy for my college wifi

Comment: See, the proxy is still active... "System Settings" -> "Network" -> "Network proxy".  What is written there?

Comment: Method : Automatic

Comment: Set that to "None", assuming you don't need a proxy where you now are.

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you want to achieve and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them in their entirety in your question. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: In my college we were told to use the proxy. With the help of askubuntu I saved it in the file etc/apt/apt.conf as per the syntax.

Comment: When I was trying to download packages from my home I had issue because of proxy. So I did search for unset proxy and did it. Also cleared my apt.conf file. Still it is trying to connect to my college proxy.

Comment: Thankyou jawtheshark. After setting it to none I used unset http_proxy and now I am able to download it from other wifi